Is tracing supported in the path schema?
When i'm trying to trace an existing transaction with geth using path schema i get:
> tracer('0xc1668976ece94d5fa97881cb538be5546b13052da5bff476863d8361da3e308f');
Error: historical state not available in path scheme yet
        at web3.js:6387:9(39)
        at send (web3.js:5116:62(29))
        at tracer (filterTrace_1.js:2:34(7))
        at <eval>:1:7(2)

Tracer function(taken from the geth EVM tracing tutorial):
tracer = function (tx) {
    return debug.traceTransaction(tx, {
        tracer:
            '{' +
            'retVal: [],' +
            'step: function(log,db) {this.retVal.push(log.getPC() + ":" + log.op.toString())},' +
            'fault: function(log,db) {this.retVal.push("FAULT: " + JSON.stringify(log))},' +
            'result: function(ctx,db) {return this.retVal}' +
            '}'
    }); // return debug.traceTransaction ...
}; // tracer = function ...

Geth startup command:
geth --mainnet --authrpc.addr localhost --authrpc.port 8551 --authrpc.vhosts localhost --authrpc.jwtsecret /tmp/jwtsecret

Does that means that there is no way to trace transactions when you using the path schema?
